# DOMdocument ting the contents of a tag

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have this code snippet and i want to to nodeValue of the `<p id="nan" ></p>` tag using PHP DOMDocument but i get an error like

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

on the following line:

```
echo $p->nodeValue;
```

My code:

```
<?php

$site = new DOMdocument();
$p = $site -> getElementById('nan');
echo $p->nodeValue;
$html = $site->saveHTML();
echo $html ;


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="nan"> Jello </p>
<ul id="list">
    <li> This is a ordered list </li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to load the HTML explicitly, using `loadHTML()` or `loadHTMLFile()`.

Comment: how do you do it hear ? can u give an example in this case ?

Comment: `$site->loadHTML('<html> ... </html>');` after `new DOMDocument`.

Comment: Simply DOMdocument class doesn't know what is text you want to parse

Answer (score 0):

as a suggestion, instead of this:

```
$site = new DOMdocument();
$p = $site -> getElementById('nan');
```

use this in a javascript function

```
var nanTextValue = document.getElementById(nan).value;
```